# how to use std forward correctly in this case

Tags: c++

Here is a class which has queue as private member and addTask() method and when i compile this i have error with std::forward:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <queue>
#include <future>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

class Pool {
    public:
        using Task = std::function<void()>;

        Pool(){}
        ~Pool(){}

        template<typename Func, typename ...Args>
        auto addTask(Func task, Args &&... arguments) -> std::future<decltype(task(arguments...))>
        {
            auto wrapper = std::make_shared<std::packaged_task<decltype(task(arguments...)) (Args...)>>(std::move(task));
            {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mEventMutex);
                mTasks.emplace([=] {
                    (*wrapper)(std::forward<Args...>(arguments...));
                });
            }
            return wrapper->get_future();         
        }

    private:
        std::queue<Task> mTasks;
        std::mutex mEventMutex;
};
```

and using it like this:

```
int task_with_argument(int value)
{
 return value;
}

addTask( task_with_argument, 10 );
```

and i am getting error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘forward(const int&)’
```

I've also tried this:

```
(*wrapper)(std::forward<Agrs>(arguments)...);
```

and again error:

```
error: binding reference of type ‘std::remove_reference<int>::type&’ {aka ‘int&’} to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers
```

Where is a problem?

Comment: [mcve] needed. cigien already solved one problem for you. Now your code bumps into the next issue. Just supply code that we can actually compile and see the error for ourselves and it will be so much easier to help you.

Comment: Change the capture clause from `[=]` to `[&]`.

Answer (score 2):

This call:

```
std::forward(arguments...)
```

is not the correct way to use `std::forward`.

Instead, you should take the arguments to the function as forwarding references:

```
addTask(Func task, Args &&... arguments)
```

and then use the arguments like this:

```
std::forward<Args...>(arguments...)
```

Comment: now i am getting this error: `error: binding reference of type ‘std::remove_reference<int>::type&’ {aka ‘int&’} to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers`. I've added how i created queue, may be problem is somewhere there and i just don't see it?

Comment: @ADV I'm not sure. Your edit is helpful, but I still can't compile the code. Your question is missing things like `mEventMutex`, etc. Please make a [mre] that I can compile, and shows only the error you're facing.

Comment: @ADV, does `task_with_argument` take an `int&`? If so, you're trying to call it with 10, which is not allowed to bind to an l-value reference. Make it take an `int`, `const int&` or `int&&` if you'd like to be able to pass temporaries.

Answer (score 0):

You attempt to apply perfect forwarding, but this does not make sense in your problem solution. To stow away a task and all its arguments, copies of the arguments have to be made. This defeats all perfect forwarding attempts.

Furthermore, you ask your `std::future` to store a `decltype(task(arguments...)`, i.e. to pick an overload that is invoked *without* perfectly forwarded arguments. It is inconsistent, to say the least, to do the actual call with perfectly forwarded arguments (if that would have made sense).

Just remove `std::forward`:

```
mTasks.emplace([=] { (*wrapper)(arguments...); });
```